# When timer reaches 0 click automatically on the button with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Here is an example of a timer http://www.prezzipazzi.com/prodotto.php?id=1809
and I need a code that when the timer reaches 0 it click automatically on the button1809.

I tried this but it does not work:

```
var waitForZeroInterval = setInterval (CheckForZero, 0);
var hasRun = false;

function CheckForZero () {

    if ( (unsafeWindow.seconds == 0)  &&  (unsafeWindow.milisec == 0) )
    {
        clearInterval (waitForZeroInterval);

        var targButton  = document.getElementById ('bottone1809');
        var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');

        clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
        targButton.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
    };

    if (!hasRun) {
        hasRun = true;
        setInterval(CheckForZero, 35000);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it click the button one time and then stop, or not click the button at all?
It looks like the `hasRun` logic is wrong.

I can't test at that site since (1) it annoys me greatly, (2) It seems to require a registration -- which I will not do.  So, **please confirm that it operates like this:**

1. You login and load an auction page -- 1809 in this example.
2. The 30-second timer starts. When it hits 0, you click.
3. The timer resets -- **Is there a delay?** -- to a new 30-second countdown but the auction remains the same.
4. Repeat, ad nauseam.

If all that is true, *and* the current code clicked the button once, then this should work:

```
var waitForZeroInterval = null;

function RestartZeroCheck () {
    waitForZeroInterval = setInterval (CheckForZero, 100);
}

function CheckForZero () {

    if ( (unsafeWindow.seconds == 0)  &&  (unsafeWindow.milisec == 0) )
    {
        clearInterval (waitForZeroInterval);

        var targButton  = document.getElementById ('bottone1809');
        var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');

        clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
        targButton.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);

        //--- After a short pause, start checking for the next timer to zero.
        setTimeout (RestartZeroCheck, 333);
    };
}

RestartZeroCheck ();
```

Note that if that works, then examining the page's structure suggests that this:

```
var targButton  = document.getElementById ('bottone1809');
```

Can be changed to this:

```
var targButton  = document.querySelector (
    "#left-inside div.post-wrapper td center input[id^='bottone']"
);
```

So that the auction number does not have to be hard-coded.

Comment: What do you mean, `The problem is the 'if (...)'`??  **Be specific**.     Also, **Answer the question I asked:** Did the button click once and stop, or did it not click at all?

Comment: the `function CheckForZero () {
if ( (unsafeWindow.seconds == 0)  &&  (unsafeWindow.milisec == 0) )
{ alert('ciao')}` doesn't work on prezzipazzi and i don't know why...

Comment: The page JS variables are different than what the question implies (`seconds` is not an int, for example).  Also, if you leave the script running in a tab and then do something in another window, Firefox will throttle the non-focused window's JS.  Finally, what you are trying to do is no-doubt against the terms of service and may be illegal where you are.

Answer (score 0):

some more update:

HTML

```
<input type="button" name="button1" id="button1" onclick="do_some();"/>
```

script

```
var waitForZeroInterval = setInterval (function(){}, 0);
var hasRun = false;

function CheckForZero () {    
   clearInterval (waitForZeroInterval);
   jQuery('#button1').click();
 }

if (!hasRun) {
    hasRun = true;
    waitForZeroInterval  = setInterval(CheckForZero(), 1000);
    }

function do_some(){
alert("thank you");
}
```

This is working fine.. i have tested. i am getting that alert after 1 sec. The button is clicked and then the do_some function is called to display alert.
You can check here [run code](http://jsfiddle.net/raj_er04/qnah2/3/)

Comment: no, do not! just use `document.getElementById("bottone1809").click()`.

Also, you don't need to ready() greasemonkey scripts.

Comment: i have updated the code after testing.. please check it now. It should work.

Comment: @Bergi you are right, dosn't need ready but document.getElementById("bottone1809").click() doesn't actually works.